# React Native Android crash - RNKeychainManager.setInternetCredentialsForServer got 6 arguments, expected 7

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-keychain

I ran into a crash at runtime in react native after upgrading a load of dependencies. There's an issue for it, but no particular help: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain/issues/205 It's also hard to nail down exact reproduction steps or the cause. Nothing in the source code, including the code of the dependency, suggests that this function requires 7 arguments. Concurrent with this issue, I stopped being able to reload the JS package on Android.

Answer (score 0):

The much more visible error is actually much less helpful in troubleshooting this than the fact the JS bundle won't load. I resolved both issues by adding an attribute to the application tag in my AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<manifest ... >
    <...other tags />
    <application
      ...
+     android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```